# How to display the numbers

Tags: java, input, numbers

I'm new to coding with Java and I'm having trouble writing this program.

User enters an integer from 0 to 9 and a pyramid is displayed. For ex:

User input: 5

```
                      1
                  2  1  2
              3  2  1  2  3
          4  3  2  1  2  3  4
      5  4  3  2  1  2  3  4  5
```

This is all I have thus far (I'm truly stumped)

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.util.Scanner'
import java.util.*;

public class pyramid
{

public pyramid()
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter a number between 1 and 20");
    int num = scan.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < num + 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < num - 1; j++)
        {
            System.out.println(" ");
        }

    }
}


}
```

Any help is welcome and appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Does the pyramid need to be crooked to the right, as in your example?

Comment: Nope, any orientation is fine! As long as what is printed (regardless of spacing of the pyramid as a whole) is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        pyramid();
    }

    public static void pyramid() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter a number between 1 and 20");
        int num = scan.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < num + 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < num - i; j++) {
                System.out.print("  ");
            }
            for (int j = i; j > 0; --j) {
                System.out.printf("%d ", j);
            }
            for (int j = 2; j <= i; ++j) {
                System.out.printf("%d ", j);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Start tabulating what you know, to find a pattern. Say you have height 3:

```
······_1
···_2 _1 _2
_3 _2 _1 _2 _3
```

Where `·` is a space for alignment purposes, `_` a space reserved for the second digit.

```
Row                 0  1  2
Spaces in front     6  3  0      (3 * (num - i - 1))
```

So you want to loop `j` to print that number of spaces, then make another loop (not inside `j`, but after it) to print the descending numbers to `1`, then another loop to print ascending numbers back to `i+1`. Using `System.out.printf` with format `%2d` will print the `_` space on single-digit numbers.